# How to clear Facebook like button cached information

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-like

Does anybody know how to clear the cached information that Facebook uses for the Like button?

I need to be able to clear a lot of pages at once making a site-wide solution ideal.

This is the website: http://www.stayin-yorkshire.net/

Answer (score 8):

If you run your pages through the Facebook linter it will clear the cache and rescrape your pages.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If you have a list of all pages on your site you can programmatically submit each URL to the Facebook linter which is easier than typing them all in:

```
curl http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json
```

Comment: By the way, it would only work for me if I added a user-agent to the request like this : `curl -A "Mozilla" http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url={YOUR_URL}&format=json`

Comment: Would you happen to know the maximum number of requests that can be made to the linter per minute / hour etc;?

Answer (score 6):

As well as [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) linked by DPS, there's a scraper API endpoint which allows you to programatically request an update of your object URL

The full details are in the [Using Self-Hosted Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#update) documentation - it involves making a HTTP POST request to

`https://graph.facebook.com/?id=<OBJECT ID OR URL>&scrape=true` - to avoid quickly hitting rate limits you should also include a valid access token with the request and make the requests slowly over a long period of time to avoid overloading the scraper or your own server